# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un select que me devuelva los registros con un valor consecutivo?

Tags: sql-server, sql, select

Tengo una tabla como la siguiente:

```
| ID | EQUIPO | GOLES | TEMPORADA |
|:--:|:------:|:-----:|:---------:|
|  1 |    A   |   0   |     3     |
|  2 |    A   |   0   |     2     |
|  3 |    A   |   0   |     1     |
|  4 |    A   |   5   |     4     |
|  5 |    B   |   0   |     1     |
|  6 |    B   |   3   |     3     |
|  7 |    B   |   0   |     2     |
|  8 |    B   |   0   |     4     |
```

Quiero devolver al equipo que tiene mayor racha con 0 goles, tomando en cuenta el orden de las temporadas, para el ejemplo anterior deberia devolver A ya que en tres partidos consecutivos tuvo 0 goles mientras que el equipo B solo tuvo 0 goles en 2 partidos consecutivos, además me gustaría saber como devolver también la cantidad de temporadas que duro la racha.

Esto es lo que llevo, aunque obviamente esto no hace lo que quiero, pero es lo más cerca que se me ocurré.

```
SELECT EQUIPO, COUNT(*)
FROM PARTIDO WHERE GOLES = 0;
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que define si un partido es _consecutivo_ de otro, la temporada o el ID? ¿qué pasaría si en el registro hay un partido del equipo A con ID X y 0 goles, seguido (por ID) de una serie de partidos de otros equipos. El siguiente partido de A, también tiene 0 goles, pero el ID no es X + 1, sino X + n. Estos partidos se consideran consecutivos, o no?
Un saludo.

Comment: Por partido consecutivo me refiero a la temporada.

Answer (score 3):

Deberías de probar tu consulta de este modo

```
SELECT EQUIPO, COUNT(TEMPORADA) AS ConteoPerdidos
FROM equipo 
WHERE GOLES = 0
GROUP BY EQUIPO
ORDER BY EQUIPO
OFFSET  0 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

**LO QUE HICE**

1. Selecciono el nombre del equipo
2. Hago el `count()` de las temporadas de cada equipo por que los agruparé
3. Le indico con el `WHERE` que solo seleccione el equipo y haga el conteo de temporadas cuando `goles` sea igual a 0
4. Agrupo por equipo
5. Ordeno por equipo (Esto es necesario para que la sentencia siguiente funcione, la que limita la cantidad de registros)
6. Con `OFFSET 0 ROWS` le indico que se salte 0 filas
7. con `FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY` le indico que tome la primer fila y sea la única que muestre la consulta final

[Enlace con el ejemplo funcionando](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=995b33aebe4013a14343406102c851c7)

Comment: Muy bueno, sin embargo está devolviendo al equipo con mayor cantidad de partidos con 0 goles, lo que yo necesito es el equipo con mayor cantidad de partidos con 0 goles consecutivos.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes lograrlo utilizando un CTE recursivo, que relacione todos los partidos de una misma racha, de manera que luego pueda aplicarse un contador sobre ellos.

```
with
Resultado as (
select 1 Id, 'A' Equipo, 0 Goles, 3 Temporada 
union all select 2, 'A', 0, 2
union all select 3, 'A', 0, 1
union all select 4, 'A', 5, 4
union all select 5, 'B', 0, 1
union all select 6, 'B', 3, 3
union all select 7, 'B', 0, 2
union all select 8, 'B', 0, 4
)
,
Base0 as (
select   Id
       , Equipo
       , Goles
       , Temporada
       , LAG(Goles) over (partition by Equipo order by Temporada) GolesAnterior
       , case when Goles = 0 and coalesce(LAG(Goles) over (partition by Equipo order by Temporada), 1) != 0 then 1 else 0 end IniciaRacha0
       , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Equipo order by Temporada) NumFilaEquipo
  from Resultado
)
,
RBase as (
select   a.Equipo
       , a.Goles
       , a.Temporada
       , a.NumFilaEquipo 
       , a.Temporada TemporadaIniciaRacha
       , a.Temporada TemporadaFinalizaRacha
  from Base0 a
 where a.IniciaRacha0 = 1
union all
select   a.Equipo
       , a.Goles
       , a.Temporada
       , a.NumFilaEquipo
       , b.TemporadaIniciaRacha
       , a.Temporada TemporadaFinalizaRacha
  from Base0 a
       inner join RBase b on b.Equipo = a.Equipo and a.Goles = 0 and a.NumFilaEquipo = b.NumFilaEquipo + 1
)
select   top 1
         a.Equipo
       , a.TemporadaIniciaRacha
       , MAX(a.TemporadaFinalizaRacha) TemporadaFinalizaRacha
       , COUNT(1) NumeroPartidosRacha
  from RBase a
 group by a.Equipo, a.TemporadaIniciaRacha
 order by count(1) desc
```

Esto me devuelve el siguiente resultado:

```
Equipo TemporadaIniciaRacha TemporadaFinalizaRacha NumeroPartidosRacha
------ -------------------- ---------------------- -------------------
A      1                    3                      3

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Lo que hecho es:

- En el CTE `Base0`, obtengo los goles del registro de la *temporada* anterior del mismo equipo, utilizando la función [`lag`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Si dicha función devuelve `null` o un valor distinto de 0, marco con un valor `1` ese registro como el *inicio* de una `racha0`. También calculo el número de fila al que pertenece la temporada para cada equipo (solo en caso que las temporadas no sean consecutivas), en la columna `NumFilaEquipo`.
- `RBase` es un CTE recursivo.

  - En la raíz, selecciono todos los registros marcados como *inicio de racha* en la columna `IniciaRacha0`
  - Luego recorro recursivamente todos aquellos registros cuyo campo `Goles` sea `0` y cuyo `NumFilaEquipo` sea consecutivo con otro nodo del arbol. Es decir, que sea consecutivo con un inicio de racha, o bien, con un registro que a su vez ya es consecutivo de uno de estos (es decir, que es parte de la misma *racha*).
  - Este CTE va a devolverme el mismo `TemporadaIniciaRacha` para todos aquellos registros que formen parte de una racha. A su vez, el campo `TemporadaFinalizaRacha` va a ir cambiando en cada uno, pues es su propia temporada.
- Ya con esta información, obtener el número de *temporadas* de una racha, es tan trivial como agrupar por equipo y `TemporadaIniciaRacha` y contar el número de registros. Adicionalmente, con max() obtengo la temporada de finalización de la racha. Finalmente, con `top 1` limito la salida de la consulta a solamente el primer registro, y con el `order by` me aseguro que este primer registro sea el del equipo con la racha de más temporadas.